# Async await issue in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to send messages to mobile numbers using message bird API, i have completed the coding part but its not sending the messages, even i can see i have sent messages and being delivered in my message bird profile. I came to know that this issue can be due to not using async and await. Here is my code,

```
api.get('/sendmessage', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.headers.authorization;
    if (req.session.id) {
        var userid = req.session.user[0].id;
        var username = userInfo.find({ id: userid }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { res.send("New Error: " + err); }
            else {
                if (!_.isEmpty(user)) {
                    var contact = user[0].contact;
                    var messagebird = require('messagebird')('ACCESS_KEY_API'); // Api for testing

                    var params = {
                        'originator': 'MessageBird',
                        'recipients': [
                            contact
                        ],
                        'body': 'Hello, world!'
                    };

                    messagebird.messages.create(params, function (err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log("Error sent to Console: " + err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(response);
                            return res.send(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    res.send("No Results");
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This API provide a fake response, i have tried with Live API as well... but didn't succeed.

Comment: Try to log `userid` to see if it's a valid objectID `console.log(userid)` , the same thing for  `contact` variable, maybe it isn't a valid phone number, check the api key too

Comment: the User id is fine, i printed user id in console, but the problem is "it is sending message but its not recieving on my mobile number"

Comment: check the phone number in `contact` variable, maybe it's not what you are expecting

Comment: contact variable contain mobile number with country code, it didn't worked.

Comment: is `contact` a literal object or a reference to another Mongoose document? Post your schema for `user`.